# Sum values of a Nested Dictionary with same key PYTHON

Tags: python

I have searched in the forum but havent found an option for my case.

I have this nested Dict

```
nestedDict = {5: {'B02682': 227808, 'B02598': 183263, 'B02617': 108001, 'B02512': 35536, 'B02764': 9908}, 4: {'B02598': 260549, 'B02682': 222883, 'B02617': 122734, 'B02512': 36765, 'B02764': 9504}, 1: {'B02598': 242975, 'B02682': 194926, 'B02617': 184460, 'B02512': 32509, 'B02764': 8974}, 0: {'B02617': 355803, 'B02598': 220129, 'B02682': 173280, 'B02764': 48591, 'B02512': 31472}, 2: {'B02617': 310160, 'B02598': 245597, 'B02682': 196754, 'B02512': 35021, 'B02764': 8589}, 3: {'B02617': 377695, 'B02598': 240600, 'B02682': 197138, 'B02764': 178333, 'B02512': 34370}}
```

And I need to sum the values of the elements with same key so I can get something like this

```
result = {'B02617': 1458853, 'B02598': 1393113, 'B02682': 1212789, 'B02764': 263899, 'B02512': 205673}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.  Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result={}

for i in nestedDict:
    for k in nestedDict[i]:
        if k in result:
            result[k]+=nestedDict[i][k]
        else:
            result[k]=nestedDict[i][k]

>>> print(result)

{'B02682': 1212789, 'B02598': 1393113, 'B02617': 1458853, 'B02512': 205673, 'B02764': 263899}
```

Comment: It's just one else statement more. Sorry but sometimes i prefer the old fashion solution, especially for beginners that probably do not want to get involved with more complex structures

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```py
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int) # equivalent to defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for d in nestedDict.values():
    for key, value in d.items():
        result[key] += value

# if result must be of type dict uncomment the following line
# result = dict(result)
```